# Inherited Well-Poweredness.

Tags: category-theory

I am reading a proof of SAFT, where the following fact is used: If category $D$ is well-powered, and $G: D\rightarrow C$ is a functor, then $(A\downarrow G)$ is well-powered, for any $A$ in $C$. The explanation given is the following: the forgetful functor preserves monos (as it creates and so preserves limits) so the subobjects of $(B,f)$ in $(A\downarrow G)$ are those subobjects $B'\rightarrow B$ in $D$ for which
$f: A \rightarrow GB$ factors through $GB'\rightarrow GB$. This is certainly true.

My question is: but isn't it enough just to observe that being a monic in $(A\downarrow G)$ is the same thing as being a monic in $D$, with the additional requirement that certain triangles commute? So, given any object $(B, f)$ in $(A\downarrow G)$  the subobjects of $(B, f)$ will just be the monics $m:B'\rightarrow B$ in $D$ that satisfy the additional property as stated above. i.e, it will be a subset of the poset of subojects of $B$ in $D$. I do not see the need for invoking the forgetful functor here.

edit: My reasoning is flawed. See my comment to Kevin below. I still think this can be done from scratch, but I do not see how yet. Here is what I came up with in the meantime: Consider objects $A$ and $B$ and a morphsim $f$ as shown, in any category $C$, and the square 
\begin{array}{&&} 
A & \to & A \\ 
\downarrow & & \downarrow f \\ 
A & \stackrel{f}{\to} & B
\end{array}

It is easy to show that $f$ is monic $\Leftrightarrow $ the square is a pullback. Since the forgetful functor $U$ preserves limits, and therefore pullbacks we have $f$ monic in $(A\downarrow G)\Leftrightarrow $ square is a pullback in $(A\downarrow G) \Leftrightarrow $ the square is a pullback in $D \Leftrightarrow $ $f$ is a monic in $D$.

This seems a little cleaner than using the full force of $U$, i.e. that it creates small limits. Here, we just use the fact that it preserves pullbacks.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can argue directly that if $g:(B',f')\to (B,f)$ is a monomorphism in the comma category it's a monomorphism in $D$, since if $gh=gk$ in $D$ then $gh=gk$ in $(A\downarrow G)$ when we take the view $h:(B'',?)\to (B',f')$ and $k:(B'',?)\to (B',f')$...as of the edit, I don't see this argument going through for monos as it does for epis.

Comment: You still have to prove the forgetful functor preserves pullbacks (hence monos). To prove it preserves  pullbacks, and limits in general is not trivial is it? It took me some time to do.

Comment: The preservation of limits is fairly clear, by general arguments. Showing the preservation of monomorphisms directly requires more care, as above.

Comment: @Zhen: if $gh=gk$ in $D$, once you know that any arrow in $D$ can be viewed as an arrow in $(A\downarrow G)$, you're done because then $h$ and $k$ being in $(A\downarrow G)$, you just use the fact that if $g:(B',f')\to (B,f)$ is a mono in the comma category, then $h=k$, which is also true in $D$ by construction. Or am I missing something here? The preservation of limits by U is not hard but it seems like it's more work than is necessary.

Comment: But you do use it in the proof of SAFT.

Comment: @Zhen: or you can show directly that the comma category has products and equalizers.

Comment: Actually, this argument no longer seems to work. I proved that epis in $A\downarrow G$ are epis in $D$, but to use the same argument on monos it looks like I'd have to pull a factorization of $f'$ through $h$ and $k$ out of thin air. The point is that we would need to know any arrow in $D$ can be viewed as an arrow in the comma category *with arbitrary structure map on the codomain, which is not by any means the case. Your last comment reads as if you're claiming that showing the comma category has products and equalizers will imply it's well-powered?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, you are right. My reasoning is flawed. Suppose $g$ is a monic in the comma category. If $gh=gk$ in $D$, you'd need to show that $h$ and $k$ are arrows in the comma category, which amounts to producing an arrow for which a certain triangle commutes. It is not obvious how to do this, I agree. See my edit for another proof, although I still think you can do this from scratch. I just do not see how.